# Yii2 - switch response between rest (json) and normal html output

Tags: php, ajax, rest, yii, yii2

I need a way to active rest when some one using ajax `X-Requested-With`
and deactivate that when doesn't. with this way I can handle search engine
or users without ajax.(improve SEO)

some research: (**using behaviors**)

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => \yii\web\ResponseFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'something'  => [
                    'format' => Response::FORMAT_JSON,
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

check request headers and change response.

or: (**edit rest controller**)

edit `$serializer = 'yii\rest\Serializer';` to `$serializer = null;`

or (**override after action of rest controller**)

```
public function afterAction($action, $result)
{
    $result = parent::afterAction($action, $result);
    return $this->serializeData($result);
}
```

and remove `serializeData()` some how...

but what is the ultimate way?

I think these ways are not fine...

Comment: I think you need to extend ContentNegotiator (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-contentnegotiator.html).